# How can I uncover why my .Net Core app is using so much unmanaged memory?

Tags: linux, .net-core, memory

I'm using .Net Core (6) on linux and wondering why it uses so much memory. I know the nominal amount of objects on the heap is tiny, in comparison to the process working set (we're talking 10 MB vs 1 GB or 2 orders of magnitude), and there aren't a lot of threads (and stacks). So, it seems unlikely that the application's data, in *managed* memory is the problem.

This leaves possible other reasons for memory wastage such as everything else in unmanaged memory
-copied assembly binaries that got loaded? (< 100 MB of files)
-other library dependencies?
-JIT overhead?
-other constants and data loaded by the CLR? (codepages and stuff?)
-other unmanaged memory allocations, that are referenced? Like, by the OS libraries?

So, what is the best way to narrow it down?

Comment: I have a .NET 8 app where I develop on Windows and deploy on Linux ARM. When running on Windows it only consumes 40MB, but on Linux it is constantly at 130MB. I am also investingating why, and I might do a memory profile later. Meanwhile I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1463348/high-memory-consumption-of-net-6-app-on-linux